# Is it possible to ship an IOS app with different data on each app?

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating an IOS app using swift. I am wondering if it is possible to add different data to each app that is downloaded.

Say I have an app on the App Store:

User 1 downloads the app and the array "fruits" is set to:

```
["banana", "apple", "orange"]
```

but if user 2 downloads the same app the array would be set differently:

```
["pineapple", "strawberry", "mango"]
```

and user 3

```
["blueberry", "peach", "watermelon"]
```

I know this is easily possibly by downloading the array of fruits, but I am looking to do this without connecting to the internet or exposing the entire list of fruits (e.g. having all of the fruits and then choosing them randomly)

Comment: If it's possible, it'd probably have to happen at download time.  The app doesn't run any code until it's downloaded though, after which you say you don't want the app to connect to the internet. What's the rationale behind not downloading the array?

Comment: My intention is to add separate urls that the app can connect to if the original api is blocked on a network. If the app is blocked, then I wouldn't be able to fetch them from my service

Comment: Short answer, no.  The application bundle that is downloaded is fixed.  You could include all of the data in the app and have it select a subset the first time it is run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is - No, you can't.

The app on the appstore is like a box. Every user gets the same box. However, as Shantanu mentions, you can show a random subset. Having said that, it won't serve the purpose of finding out working Url among the blocked ones. If you intention is to show the accessible Url to the user then you can just loop through the master list and check which are accessible. e.g. if you've 10 Urls in total then ping first to check if it's accessible. If not then move to next. Randomisation may not help to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you have to hardcode all possible array sets and then do something like this,
1. First generate a random number between 0 - 10

```
let number = Int.random(in: 0 ... 10)
```

2. Based on the generated number output specific set of array,

```
switch (number) {
   case (0):
       ["banana", "apple", "orange"]
   case (1):
       ["pineapple", "strawberry", "mango"]
   case (2):
       ["blueberry", "peach", "watermelon"]
   default:
       print("And Likewise you have different datasets without downloading")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible on downloading app from the apple store.

But sharing you a note through which it could be possible.

This is possible only when :-

1). SignIn process required.

2). The SignIn must be managed with the CoreData(Local Database).

3). You need to check the count of the array for users signed In to the app by getting if form the local Database.

4). According to that count you will change the array of fruits for different users.

There is no way of doing this scenario on downloading through App Store. Only way is manage this with the local Database with SignIn process.

Answer (score -1):

According to your requirement,

> without connecting to the Internet

Then you have to ship the data set with the application bundle. If you store those data in a file inside the project, here how you can retrieve it.

```
func linesFromResource(fileName: String) -> [String] {

    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: nil) else {
        fatalError("Resource file for \(fileName) not found.")
    }
    do {
        let content = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        return content.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    } catch let error {
        fatalError("Could not load strings from \(path): \(error).")
    }
}
```

My data set file is as below.

```
apple
apricot
avocado
banana
berry
cantaloupe
cherry
citron
citrus
...
```

Then, here I have provided different data set to different user. In my case, I am changing the number of elements in the array as well.

```
let result : Array = linesFromResource(fileName: "DataSet")
print(result.shuffled().prefix(Int.random(in: 0 ..< result.count)))
```

By doing like this your other requirement

> exposing the entire list of fruits

also fulfill.

I accept that you cannot download same app with different data without at least having a single service call. What I gave here is an optional solution. You can download and run the code from this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/AnujAroshA/ArrayFromResourceSO) and get an idea what I meant.